# How to configure discovery and deployer microservice in Active/Passive (fail-over) High Availability architecture

Tags: publishing, web8, discovery-service

We want to setup publishing in Active/Passive (fail-over) High Availability architecture using SDL Web8 microservices. We have two production application server .Should we install Discovery and deployer microservice on both server??Discovery Service database will be separate for each instance ??

Comment: Sorry, this question is too vague to be given a definitive answer

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the SDL documentation on Scaling Content Delivery here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-5570B671-C4CD-4CC9-943B-489E5390C13E